# Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, exoplayer

I'd like to modify ExoPlayer's code and for this i have to add it as a module.
I added a folder `'libraries'` and put the ExoPlayer folder inside.
[image]

Then i added include `:libraries:ExoPlayer` in the project settings.gradle. Finally in the Project Structure settings i added `:libraries:ExoPlayer` as a dependency to my project, but after this, i keep getting this error :

```
Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :libraries:ExoPlayer.
```

And this is the content of the `settings.gradle` of my app.

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:ExoPlayer'
```

Thank you for your future help.

Answer (score 1):

`ExoPlayer` is an own multi-project build, defined in its `settings.gradle` file. You cannot simply import this multi-project build into your own multi-project build, as multi-project builds are not hierarchical in Gradle. There is at most **one** `settings.gradle` file per build process considered. Which one depends on where you execute gradle.

The easiest would be if you simply depend on `ExoPlayer`s released artifacts.

If you need a fresh build, because you need changes that were not released yet, you should still declare a dependency on the pre-built artifacts and then use the Gradle composite build feature to replace the artifacts by a sub-build that is executed. This in turn can be an own multi-project build without problem.

Please find more information about it in the Gradle Userguide.